# VIM Color scheme not loading by default

Tags: vim, macvim

When I do

```
:colorscheme vilight
```

it loads the color scheme fine.

So I added

```
colorscheme vilight
```

to my .vimrc but its not loading it on start. Am I missing something?

Also in my config

```
set background=dark 
syntax on
colorscheme vilight 
set lines=60 columns=200
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Are you using gvim? It is possible that your .gvimrc or the system's gvimrc file is overriding the colorscheme selection from your .vimrc.

Comment: I'm using MacVim, but I'm facing the same issue. I could not find a .gvimrc in my home directory. Could you help me?

Answer (score 9):

Sometimes it helps to put the colorscheme **at the end** of the _gvimrc .gvimrc file
which is read (after SYNTAX ON). Also be sure that HOME is read.
Sometimes gvim still reads from the installation path.

Answer (score 8):

For Macvim, the solution would be add the following into your .vimrc:

```
let macvim_skip_colorscheme=1
```

Then it will respect your choice in .vimrc.

Comment: I had to use this when the theme was not properly setting the `g:colors_name` value properly. Fixing this in the theme solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem! MacVim does not load my colorscheme on start. However, vim run from the command line does. Is this a MacVim issue then?

I cleared my .vimrc and just left the colorscheme lines and it still does not work.

```
set background=dark
colorscheme solarized
syntax on
```

However, doing

```
:set background=dark
:colorscheme solarized
```

after startup works.

UPDATE: I found out that MacVim loads both .vimrc and .gvimrc and in my case, stuff in .gvimrc was the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `syntax on` in your `.vimrc`?

Comment: yep

syntax on
colorscheme vilight

Comment: Hrm... I just tried your config on my machine (not with `vilight`, but a colorscheme I have installed) and it works.  You have `vilight.vim` in `$HOME/.vim/colors/`, correct?

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. Commenting out `set background=light` in file `.gvim` fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Really odd but this finally fixed issue on my mac.  

Didn't work:
```set background=dark```

Did work:
```set background=light```

Gotta get my peachpuff colorscheme!

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too when I took a .vimrc from gVim for windows and used it with MacVim.

I noticed that the vi that comes with snow leopard complains about lines ending with ^M (aka carriage return, or "\r"). After converting the dos-style newlines to unix-style the problem was solved. (*)

MacVim does not complain about this, but apparently does have a problem loading the .vimrc when it contains dos-style newlines.

(*) - Dos/windows style new lines are composed of a carriage return and a line feed ('\r\n'), unix style newlines contain only a line feed ('\n').

Answer (score 1):

Just add line "source .vimrc" in the end of .gvimrc

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **MacVim** I had problems loading downloaded color schemes too. I found out that if you move the color schemes to:

`/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/runtime/colors`

Then it would work in your .gvimrc

Answer (score 1):

For MacVim users, deleting the following native vimrc and gvimrc probably works.

```
rm /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/vimrc
rm /Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim/gvimrc
```