# Macvim won't load specific color scheme by default

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm having a problem similar to [VIM Color scheme not loading by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637929/vim-color-scheme-not-loading-by-default)

Except I am having the problem with the gentooish theme found here http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2474

For some reason macvim refuses to load this colorscheme by default.

My vimrc file is as follows, I do not have a .gvimrc file.

```
:set term=xterm-256color
:set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme gentooish
```

But once I have macvim opened if I do :colorscheme gentooish it will load fine. Also it does load by default if I type vim on the command line. It just won't load by default in macvim.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

MacVim loads its own default gvimrc file, which applies a default colorscheme. Since gvimrc files are processed *after* vimrc files, the colours of your `:colorscheme` instruction are overwritten by the ones from the default gvimrc.

There are two solutions: Create your own gvimrc file and put the colorscheme command there:

```
$ cd
$ echo "colorscheme gentooish" > .gvimrc
```

Alternatively, put the following line in your vimrc, which prevents MacVim from applying its own colorscheme (see `:h macvim-colorscheme`).

```
let macvim_skip_colorscheme = 1
```

Comment: Thanks guys, creating a .gvimrc with colorscheme gentooish worked!

Comment: That's absolute nonsense. I have been using MacVim for more than two years with `colorscheme somename` in my `~/.vimrc`, no `~/.gvimrc` and no `let macvim_skip_colorscheme = 1` without a single colorscheme issue.

Comment: @romainl I also have an older MacVim where it just works as it does for you. The `macvim_skip_colorscheme` variable seems to be a new-ish addition.

Comment: I have been runnning the latest snapshot 66 (7.3.754) since two weeks and have been running snapshot 64 for a few months before and other forgotten builds for 2 years without ever encountering any colorscheme issue. Do you have the same issue as the OP?

Comment: @romainl Interesting. I always had my `:colorscheme solarized` command in my gvimrc as I feel that's the proper place for MacVim, and it works, of course. So to answer your question, no, we both don't have the issue OP had.

Comment: I had to use `macvim_skip_colorscheme` when the theme was not properly setting the `g:colors_name` value properly. Fixing this in the theme solved the issue.

Answer (score 5):

1. `:` is not needed in your `~/.vimrc`.
2. `term` and `t_Co` are terminal-specific options. MacVim being a GUI for Vim doesn't care about them. If you don't use Vim in a terminal, those two lines are not needed.
3. `set background=dark` makes Vim do a few hardly noticeable but nifty things: it is set by Vim automatically and generally overwritten by your colorscheme. You can safely drop it from your `~/.vimrc`.

Just to make sure we are on the same boat, could you confirm that:

- your `.vimrc` path is `~/.vimrc`?
- your colorscheme path is `~/.vim/colors/gentooish.vim`?