# MacVim colorscheme on load

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, color-scheme

I have installed a new colorscheme. I added it to my `.vimrc` but when I load up macvim its not loading up. After loading a file if I type `:colorscheme sourcerer` it loads up. What am I missing here?

```
" General -----------------------
set nocompatible             " Makes vim better
scriptencoding utf-8         " Setting everything to UTF-8
set encoding=utf-8
set history=256
set timeoutlen=250 
set clipboard+=unnamed
let g:autotagTagsFile = ".git/tags"
set tags=.git/tags;$HOME/.tags

set nobackup
set nowritebackup
set directory=/tmp//
set noswapfile

set hlsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set incsearch

let mapleader = ','
let maplocalleader = '  '
let g:netrw_banner = 0


" Formatting --------------------
set nowrap

set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

set backspace=indent
set backspace+=eol
set backspace+=start

set autoindent
set cindent
set indentkeys-=0#
set cinkeys-=0#
set cinoptions=:s,ps,ts,cs
set cinwords=if,else,while,do
set cinwords+=for,switch,case

" Visual ------------------------
syntax on

set showmatch

colorscheme sourcerer

if has('gui_running')
    set guifont=InputMono:h14

    if has('mac')
    set noantialias
    endif
endif

set novisualbell
set noerrorbells
set vb t_vb=

" Plugins ------------------------
filetype off 

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'xero/sourcerer.vim'

call vundle#end() 
filetype plugin indent on
```

Comment: It seems that my answer was over here on how to fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802689/macvim-wont-load-specific-color-scheme-by-default

Comment: Do you have an error message? My guess is that `colorscheme sorcerer` should be placed after the `Plugin 'xero/sourcerer.vim'` line. (Potentially after the `vundle#end()`)

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the line containing `colorscheme sourcerer` below the Vundle setup stuff. It seems like it should have given you some related error. With your original `.vimrc` I’m given the message:

```
Error detected while processing /home/xyz/.vimrc:
line   50:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'sourcerer'No protocol specified

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

But moving the `colorscheme` line to the bottom works well.

Comment: Well I found out that MacVim will load its own .gvimrc file that loads after my vimrc file. To fix I had create .gvimrc and add my colorscheme to that